# How can I get an "Applications, Places" menu on the top panel in Unity?

Tags: unity, 11.10, gui

I've figured out how to kill the Launcher (in Unity 2D, which is what I'm using on my laptop), and now I want to put an Applications and Places menu on the top panel so that it is always there.

This is what I want:

[image: Menu]

However, the top panel in Unity is really hard to work with. I can't right click on it, move it, add apps to it... it's like it's made out of stone.

How can I get it to take a menu, and place that menu where I want?

I am willing to accept variants on the exact software that drives the menu, just so long as it is permanently affixed in the top left of the screen, and it is a drop down menu. Bonus points if it has a "recentl documents" menu.

I am ***not*** interested in running "Gnome Classic". It is problematic in all sorts of other ways. I am looking to customize Unity. Please no suggestions to log out and log in again using Gnome Classic. Thanks.

Comment: The effort to-do this would be excessive - this is built into the unity desktop.  If you dont want to use gnome-classic then can I suggest you look at some brilliant traditional WIMP environments such as XFCE and Lubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't.

The closest you can get is using an application indicator called [ClassicMenu Indicator](https://launchpad.net/classicmenu-indicator), but that will be on the right-hand side with all the other indicators:

[image]